# How to search by certain objects keys values

Tags: mongodb

First sorry for my bad English!

Suppose this document looks like this:

```
{

    "id": "598969845c274c145a935994",
    "contract_ref": "ABCDEF1234",
    "currency": "USD",
    "per_unit_cost": [
      {
        "size": 22,
        "price": 1000
      },
      {
        "size": 42,
        "price": 1500
      }
    ]
  },

{

    "id": "598969845c274c145a93599b",
    "contract_ref": "ABCDEF1234",
    "currency": "USD",
    "per_unit_cost": [
      {
        "size": 22,
        "price": 1234
      }
    ]
  }
```

How do you find 'per_unit_cost.size' that exactly match with '$all' [22], i.e. retrieve the second document and ignore the first?

Comment: By asking it to match where there is only **one** array element of course. Which is actually `.find({ "per_unit_cost.size": 22, "per_unit_cost": { "$size": 1 } })` or as `.find({ "per_unit_cost.size": 22,  "per_unit_cost.1": { "$exists": false } })` if that makes more sense to the logic.

Comment: Great thank you !

find({ "per_unit_cost.size":  { '$all': array}, "per_unit_cost": { "$size": array.length } })